# SNAT/Masquerade not modifying the Source IP occasionally

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

We do SNAT in our system in the POSTROUTING chain. But we find that once in a while the source IP did not get modified. The packet is going out with the internal IP.

We are using IP Tables version - 1.6.2
Linux Kernel version - 4.14.78

Following are the NAT rules:

```
# iptables -S -t nat
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o wwan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

In the above wwan0 is the default gateway.

How to fix this problem.

Snapshot of TCP Dump. The internal IP's (172.16..) are highlighted. The translated IP is 100.86.203.169. We can find several instances of successful translation.

```
17:13:51.939700 IP 100.86.203.169.47554 > 135.sub-198-224-172.myvzw.com.domain: 64282+ AAAA? connectivitycheck.gstatic.com. (47)
17:13:52.033482 IP 135.sub-198-224-172.myvzw.com.domain > 100.86.203.169.47554: 63258 1/0/0 A 172.217.11.163 (63)
17:13:52.033598 IP 100.86.203.169.hostmon > 224.0.0.252.hostmon: UDP, length 27
17:13:52.042355 IP 135.sub-198-224-172.myvzw.com.domain > 100.86.203.169.47554: 64282 1/0/0 AAAA 2607:f8b0:4007:804::2003 (75)
17:13:52.043389 IP 100.86.203.169 > lax28s15-in-f3.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 34628, seq 0, length 64
17:13:52.132848 IP lax28s15-in-f3.1e100.net > 100.86.203.169: ICMP echo reply, id 34628, seq 0, length 64
17:13:52.237290 IP **172.16.9.59.63478** > lax31s14-in-f14.1e100.net.443: UDP, length 1350
17:13:52.366892 IP 100.86.203.169.hostmon > 224.0.0.252.hostmon: UDP, length 27
17:13:52.416431 IP **172.16.9.68.45839** > lax17s14-in-f14.1e100.net.https: Flags [F.], seq 1838160668, ack 751548505, win 373, options [nop,nop,TS val 31214649 ecr 2926508259], length 0
17:13:52.419421 IP **172.16.9.68.45840** > lax17s14-in-f14.1e100.net.https: Flags [F.], seq 3938547017, ack 4273274368, win 373, options [nop,nop,TS
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You can't expect anybody to comment on your problem without knowing your POSTROUTING rules. Based on the information you gave me, all I can say "your POSTROUTING chain needs debugging". So please tell us the rules and the expected result.

Comment: Added the details

Comment: I guess that this system is a router, and 172.16.9.59/68 are the addresses of some devices on the internal network. I also guess that you ran something like `tcpdump -i wwan0`. What is strange is the numeric port *443* in the occurrence of 172.16.9.59, and the symbolic port *https* in the occurrences of 172.16.9.68, which make my wonder if you pasted together several `tcpdump` outputs. UDP with port 443 is also strange, but I am not a networking expert. Unfortunately I have no solution, but you may want to add the information that I guessed to the question (if I guessed right).